# Change ionic title dynamically

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to change the title of my ionic page dynamically based on a variable as follows,But it is not working,it showing an error.

```
<ion-view view-title='{{type == "nhs" : "NHS" : "Other"}} Prescription'  cache-view="false">
```

[image]

Comment: Just an alternate suggestion... try using the `$ionicNavBarDelegate.title('New Title');` inside the controller. See their docs for an example http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had issues with non-hardcoded views titles. The solution I found is to use the [`ion-nav-title`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavTitle/) directive:

```xml
<ion-view cache-view="false">
  <ion-nav-title ng-bind="{{type == 'nhs' ? 'NHS' : 'Other'}} Prescription"></ion-nav-title>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

it might be because of syntax error .

`condition ? expr1 : expr2`

try this

`<ion-view title={{type == 'nhs' ? 'NHS' : 'Other'}} cache-view="false" >`

or use `ng-if` condition

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-view title="{{(type == 'nhs') ? 'NHS' : 'Other'}} Prescription"  cache-view="false">
```